# How to make iterative API calls without blocking other code wtih Javascript and NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async-await, fetch-api

I am working on an application that makes multiple API calls. The API uses pagination, which limits the number of results and returns a cursor to be used with subsequent calls if more data is needed.

Here is my current code:

```
async function getData(url, cursor) {

    // Adds the cursor to the API URL.
    cursorUrl = url + "&cursor=" + cursor;
    // Uses fetch to make the API call.
    result = await fetch(cursorUrl);

    return result.json()
}

async function getAllData() {

    // Page limit
    const pageLimit = 3;
    // Number of "pages" of found. Default page size is 50.
    let pagesSorted = 0;
    // The cursor to use if finding multiple pages. Default is null for first call.
    let passedCursor = "";
    // Array to hold cumulitive data.
    let cumulitiveData = [];

    while (passedCursor != null && pagesSorted < pageLimit) {
        await getData(appendedUrl, passedCursor)
            .then(data => {

                // Add data to cumulitiveData array
                cumulitiveData.push(data)
                // Add one to total pages sorted.
                pagesSorted += 1;
                // Record cursor for next call
                passedCursor = data["cursor"];

                if (passedCursor == null) {
                    console.log("Reached end of responses from API.")
                } if (pagesSorted >= pageLimit) {
                    console.log("Page limit reached.")
                }
            });
    }

    return cumulitiveData
}
```

This code works, but it blocks anything else from happening (like other API calls) until it is done. It can sometimes take a long time, and I'd like to perform other actions while it is working.

I have been stuck on this for so long, any help is greatly appreciated. I'm new to programming, so any critique on my code overall is welcome.

Comment: This code does not block other things from happening.  At the `await fetch(cursorUrl);`, other things can happen just fine.

Answer (score 0):

As implied by jfriend00 in the question comments, that is the basics of JavaScript asynchronicity.

Unlike other languages, where a code blocks a thread, and you need to "spawn" new threads to achieve parallel tasks, in JavaScript runtime, asynchronous tasks are queued, and when they are waiting for an external event (here a response from your external API), other tasks can run.

For example, if you have:

```js
setInterval(() => console.log("every 1 second"), 1000);

getAllData();

async function getAllData() {
  while (notDone) {
    console.log("getData");
    await getData();
  }
}
```

...you would see a log like:

```
getData
every 1 second
every 1 second
getData
every 1 second
every 1 second
getData
every 1 second
```

Showing that asynchronous tasks are interleaved.

Comment: This makes a lot more sense! Thank you for the explanation.